# Removing addresses from Column

Tags: mysql

I have a column within my database that holds text similar to this

`CNEWS # Trinidad : "By Any Means Necessary" Watson Duke Swims And Sails To Toco http://somewebsitehere.com`

What can I do to remove the entire http address from the column? Please note that some links may be broken so it may have `http:// somewebsitehere.com`

I was thinking of using a substring index but not sure that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use whichever your favorite programming language is to iterate through the rows in the table, pluck out that column, apply a regular expression replacement rule to it, then update the row in the table with the new value.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
theRows = SELECT * FROM TheTable WHERE 1;
foreach row in theRows
BEGIN
    oldColumnValue = row[theColumnName]
    // Removes any link appearing at the end of the column
    newColumnValue = oldColumnValue.replace(/http:\/\/[^\s]*$/, '')
    UPDATE TheTable SET theColumnName = newColumnValue WHERE id = row[id]
END
```

For something as small and specific as this, you could use perl with the DBI library to connect to mySQL.  Here's a useful resource on regular expressions if you want to go more into it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html